# ruby - what is wrong with the following array and target sum code?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, debugging, sum

Two-Sum

1. Define a method, `two_sum`, that accepts an array and a target sum (integer) as arguments.
2. The method should return true if any two integers in the array sum to the target.
3. Otherwise, it should return false. Assume the array will only contain integers.

---

```
def two_sum(array, target)
    i = 0
    sum = []
    while i < array.max
        i = i + 1
        b = i + i
        sum.push(b)
    end
    sum.include?(target)
end

puts "------Two Sum------"

puts two_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 8) == true     #(im getting true)

puts two_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 18) == false   #(im getting true)

puts two_sum([1,3,6], 6) == false          #(im getting false)

puts two_sum([1,8,2,1], 0) == false        #(im getting true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to speed the calculations when performance is important, particularly when the array is large and contains many duplicate values.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def two_sum(arr, target)
  return true if target.even? && arr.count(target/2) > 1
  st = Set.new
  arr.uniq.each do |n|
    return true if st.include?(target-n)
    st << n
  end
  false
end
```

**Examples**

```
two_sum [1, 4, -4, 4, 5], 6  #=> true
two_sum [1, 3, -4, 3, 4], 6  #=> true
two_sum [1, 3, -4, 3, 5], 5  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

The code for even values of `target` serves two purposes:

- it short-circuits the calculations when the array contains a value that equals one-half of `target`, and that value appears at least twice in the array; and
- should the aforementioned code not return `true`, it permits the removal of duplicate values in `arr` before the remaining calculations are performed.

For the first example the steps are as follows.

```
arr = [1, 4, -4, 4, 5]
target = 6

target.even?
  #=> 6.even? => true
arr.count(target/2) > 1
  #=> arr.count(3) > 1
  #=> 1 > 1
  #=> false
```

so `true` is not returned.

```
st = Set.new
  => #<Set: {}>
b = arr.uniq
  #=> [1, 4, -4, 5]
```

The first element of `b` is now passed to the block.

```
n = 1
st.include?(target-n)
  #=> st.include?(6-1) => false as the set is empty
st << n
  #=> #<Set: {1}>
```

The next steps are as follows.

```
n = 4
st.include?(target-n)
  #=> st.include?(6-4) => false
st << n
  #=> #<Set: {1, 4}>

n = -4
st.include?(target-n)
  #=> st.include?(6-(-4)) => false
st << n
  #=> #<Set: {1, 4, -4}>

n = 5
st.include?(target-n)
  #=> st.include?(6-5) => true
```

so `true` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The ruby solution looks like:

```
def two_sum(array, target)
  array.combination(2).any? { |v| v.reduce(:+) == target }
end
```

[`Array#combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-combination) returns all the combinations of two elements and [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) returns `true` if the block evaluates to `true` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Consider writing the block `{ |a,b| a+b == target }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland nope; I do use `reduce` on purpose: that way changing the code to use, say, combinations of 3 is as easy as changing `2` to `3`.

Comment: Then how about `{ |v| v.sum == target }`?

Answer (score 0):

You loop through each element of the array, which is a good start. Inside this loop, you need to try adding together each pair of elements. At the moment, all you're pushing to your sum array is `i+i`: the index doubled (i.e. every even number from 0 to double the largest element of your array).

You could attempt to sum each pair of elements by having two loops, one inside the other. They'd both iterate through the elements of the array. In your inner loop, you'd attempt to add the current element from the outer loop to the current element from the inner loop. If you get any matches, you can return true and quit immediately; otherwise return false.