# Best approach to find two elements from unsorted array having sum as defined in inputs

Tags: arrays, ruby

For example, I have an array of unsorted integers

```
array = [ 2,5,3,6,33,11,7,23,8,50,9 ]
```

With minimum iteration, how can I find two elements having sum as 10?

**Approach 1: that I assume**

1. First of all, make another array as a copy of a defined one.
2. By using For loop, iteration on elements by adding the first element with rest of the elements, if I got 10 then break the loop. But it will go n times because we did not the position of the next element.
3. In the first iteration, if I don't find any element, then I will remove the selected element to reduce the comparison of second-time iterations.
4. In the same way, I will go with rest of the elements, but again its n-1 comparison.

I tried my best to find the best approach but did not get any solution.

Comment: Please show your efforts as well. Post the code, and highlight the point where you're facing problem. This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @31piy - Sure give me some minutes

Comment: I didn't think the original post that worse, but the edit adding the last paragraph made it bad.Don't write that kind of things in the question.

Comment: You don't need to consider elements greater than 10.

Comment: Are the elements unique?

Comment: @SagarPandya - Yes consider elements are unique. agree with elements greater than 10

Comment: @SagarPandya, `-5 + 15 #=> 10`. :-) Also, why do you care if they are unique?

Comment: @Cary I'm assuming they are all positive of course! Re: unique, I just thought if there isn't a corresponding `b` for `a`, then no point trying for `a` again (should it come up). Just thinking out loud:). Also we may consider using sets.

Comment: @SagarPandya if `a` is `5`, the corresponding `b` would be `5` as well.

Comment: @Stefan if the elements are unique then there can't be another `5` can there?

Comment: @SagarPandya of course, I just wanted to point out that there is a use case for having duplicates.

Comment: @SagarPandya, yes on sets. This question seemed familiar. I thinks it's the same as  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367467/ruby-what-is-wrong-with-the-following-array-and-target-sum-code) SO question. I provided an answer there that employs a set.

Answer (score 6):

You can make it approximately O(n) by remembering the amount we miss by on each value:

```
def foo(array, target = 10)
  h = {}
  array.each do |value|
    return [h[value], value] if h.key?(value)
    h[target - value] = value
  end
  nil
end

foo([ 2,5,3,6,33,11,7,23,8,50,9 ], 10)
=> [3, 7]
```

We could also use a Set, which has the same basic flow:

```
require "set"

def foo(array, target = 10)
  seen = Set.new
  array.each do |value|
    return [target - value, value] if seen.include?(target - value)
    seen << value
  end
  nil
end

foo([ 2,5,3,6,33,11,7,23,8,50,9 ], 10)
=> [3, 7]
```

The two options are identical cost behind the scenes (because Ruby's Set is implemented on top of Hash); I prefer the semantic of remembering which value we still need [and which original value that goes with], but it's up to you which one you find reads better.

---

The other other option is to open with `array.to_set` -- that means more [though still linear] work for the computer (because it converts the whole array to a set, instead of just the elements until it finds a match), but makes the code simpler to read because the loop only has one job:

```
require "set"

def foo(array, target = 10)
  available = array.to_set
  if match = array.find { |value| available.include?(target - value) }
    [match, target - match]
  end
end

foo([ 2,5,3,6,33,11,7,23,8,50,9 ], 10)
=> [2, 8]
```

Notice it finds a different match -- the previous algorithm returned the first match to have its second number appear; the new one returns the first match to have its first number appear.

Comment: (Not _actually_ O(n) because the `h.key?` call has non-linear complexity, but as a mental heuristic, it's probably close enough)

Comment: Smart approach. Likely the least time complexity used and be possible to solve. May or not be the "most efficient" without benchmarks to compare, but does answer how to do with minimum iterations. :-)

Comment: Great! I did a benchmark, this is really fast in case of large sets. `100000.times{array << rand(0..100)}`. As my solution :). It returns a different pair of addends.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.combination(2).find { |a,b| a+b == 10 }
  #=> [2, 8]
```

`nil` would have been returned had there been no two elements that sum to `10`. For example,

```
array.combination(2).find { |a,b| a+b == 1000 }
  #=> nil
```

See [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination).

Here's another way.

```
def find_pair(arr, tot)
  if tot.even?
    half = tot/2
    return [half, half] if arr.count(half) > 2
  end 
  a = arr.uniq.sort
  p = a.find { |n| a.bsearch { |m| m >= tot-n } }
  p ? [tot-p, p] : nil
end

find_pair(array, 10)
  #=> [8, 2]
```

Comment: Will this approach cost me with an increase in memory?

Comment: No, because `combination`, when used without a block (the block is `find`'s), returns an enumerator. See the doc. Also, `find` "short-circuits" the calculation, stopping as soon as it finds a pair that sums to `10` (if any do).

Comment: but the complexity is still O(n^2) in the worst case

Comment: if the array is unordered - then yes, but if you sort an array (which can be done with a smaller complexity), then in order to find the pair O(n) iterations needed

Comment: Why not add a reject, just in case of large sets? `array.reject { |e| e  >=  10  }.combination(2).....`

Comment: @IgorDrozdov, I took your suggestion and added another method to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @iGian, good suggestion if we know the array contains no negative values.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a more verbose nested loop, **where array contains no negative values**:

```
def find_elements(array, sum)
  array.each_with_index do |x, ix|
    next if x > sum
    array.each_with_index do |y, iy|
      next if ix == iy || y > sum
      return [x, y] if x + y == sum
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

**Is it faster in case of large sets?**

**EDIT:** after my benchmark the speed is comparable with the solution from [mattewd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890370/5239030). For example `100000.times{array << rand(0..100)}`. It returns a different pair of addends.